# Setting id for root view crashes android app

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup, butterknife

As a quick visualization, this is what my layout looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="me.smac89.sample.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/cards_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I set an ID (`android:id=""`) for the Coordinator layout, the app crashes upon start up, however removing the id allows it to run normally. What is going on? Why does setting an ID for the root view cause the app the crash?

I've seen people using this `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` to get the root view; is this the only way to obtain the rootview?

---

**Crash log**

> 07-06 18:30:42.253 9385-9385/me.smac89.deloittepixel E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                          Process: me.smac89.deloittepixel, PID: 9385
>                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{me.smac89.sample/me.smac89.sample.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.app.Activity
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to
>   android.app.Activity
>                                                                              at butterknife.internal.Finder$2.getContext(Finder.java:34)
>                                                                              at butterknife.internal.Finder.getResourceEntryName(Finder.java:131)
>                                                                              at butterknife.internal.Finder.findRequiredViewAsType(Finder.java:86)
>                                                                              at
>   me.smac89.sample.MainActivity$$ViewBinder$InnerUnbinder.(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:32)
>                                                                              at
>   me.smac89.sample.MainActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:20)
>                                                                              at
>   me.smac89.sample.MainActivity$$ViewBinder.bind(MainActivity$$ViewBinder.java:17)
>                                                                              at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:122)
>                                                                              at me.smac89.sample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    @BindView(R.id.main_content)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @BindView(R.id.main_tab_spinner)
    Spinner spinner;

    @BindView(R.id.main_tab)
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setKeyAndSecret();
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerDummyAdapter(this));

        initTabs();
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What id do you set?

Comment: @jbarat Initially this `android:id="@+id/main_root_view"`, but after the first crash, I tried `android:id="@+id/blahblah"` and still got the same error

Comment: Where do you set that layout? How do you find view Id for root? 

Can you show the crash log?

Comment: @LiemVo See my edits above. I have a feeling this is not related to android but rather to `Butterknife`

Comment: According the log, the error is relative to casting `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout cannot be cast to android.app.Activity att`. If you don't mind, please show me the code that you find id for `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: @LiemVo, I don't use the id in code, just declared in xml and that crashes the app. See my edit above for how I did it in xml

Comment: @khredos, Can you try replay `CoordinatorLayout` with `LinearLayout`? If the crash is still happend, the problem won't relative to that widget. Otherwise, we can't use `CoordinatorLayout` in that way.

Comment: @khredos I think your feeling is correct re: relation to `Butterknife`.  I don't have `Butterknife` and your code executes without error, `id` and all.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and solved it with: Build > Clean Project